# Conditional self join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I'm trying to self join with conditions.

Is there a way where I could do this without using Union? (union works fine but the query doubles in size which I'm trying to avoid)

Below is the query I've written (any suggestion or guidance would be much appreciated!)

```
Select 
    concat(de.EthnicityText ,' - ', dec2.EthnicityText) as 'Ethnicity'
from
    dl.DimEthnicity de
inner join 
    (select dec1.EthnicityParentId, dec1.EthnicityText
     from dl.dimethnicity dec1) as dec2 on de.EthnicityID = dec2.EthnicityParentId

union all

select de.EthnicityText as 'Ethnicity'
from dl.DimEthnicity de
where de.EthnicityParentId is null
```

[image: sample table]

Comment: Please ensure data is presented as formatted text (or DDL/DML statements) - not images.

Comment: What do you mean by "the query doubles in size"?

Comment: Sorry I meant the select statement doubles.

Comment: What doubles? The amount of text to write the query? The amount of results returned? The time take to run?

Comment: The amount of text to write the query - would union be the only solution here?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're wanting to return all values, even if ParentID is null.

```
select a.EthnicityText + case when b.EthnicityText is null then '' else ' - ' + b.EthnicityText end
from DimEthnicity a
left join DimEthnicity b on b.EthnicityID = a.EthnicityParentID
```

Left join allows for the condition you're looking for (only return the self join row when it exists). More info on left joins: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: never knew you could use + in the select statement. Cheers! thank you so much Dale :)

Comment: Good call, Dale. Left join allows for the condition you're looking for (only return the self join row when it exists). More info on left joins: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: @JMartDBA add that to the answer... its encouraged to make answers as full and complete as possible rather than just working code.

Comment: `select case when deb.EthnicityText is null then '' else deb.EthnicityText + ' - '  end + dea.EthnicityText as 'Ethnicity'
from dl.DimEthnicity dea
left join dl.DimEthnicity deb on deb.EthnicityID = dea.EthnicityParentID`    - Tweaked it a little to suit my expected output